# Is Texture2D.Apply() for Unity == glTexSubImage2D on native side on Unity

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine

I have a texture in Unity which I will modify frequently. 
Now there are two options:

1. I can make changes to texture by calling setPixels and then call Texture2D.apply. I think the apply actually copies the data from CPU to GPU.
2. One option is I can modify the texture in native code by getting the texture native handle and modifying it using glTexSubImage2D functions.

Now I read the apply copies only the changed pixels to GPU not full texture but I really doubt if its possible. but if it is true does this mean that calling Texture2D.apply == glTexSubImage2Din terms of performance.

If not, what should I use if I need good performance. I actually dont want to go to native side as I will have to manage the native code on for different graphics APIs supported by Unity like opengl, DX etc

Answer (score 2):

`Texture2D.Apply()` and `glTexSubImage2D` are both used to update Texture. They both perform the-same action but they have differences in them.

- `GetPixels`, `SetPixels` and `Texture2D.Apply()` are done on the CPU.
- You should **only** use `GetPixels`, `SetPixels` and `Texture2D.Apply()` if you need individual pixels. Good example of this is when you want to send the Texture data over the network.
- `glTexSubImage2D` is done on the GPU and does not require `SetPixels` or
  `GetPixels`.
- `glTexSubImage2D` is extremely faster than `GetPixels`, `SetPixels` and `Texture2D.Apply()`.

> If not, what should I use if I need good performance. I actually dont
>   want to go to native side as I will have to manage the native code on
>   for different graphics APIs supported by Unity like opengl,

You mentioned that you will be modifying the image frequently, so **do not use** `GetPixels`, `SetPixels` and `Texture2D.Apply()`. I know it is the easiest solution but it is very slow.

For the best performance:

**1**.Use glTexSubImage2D

Pass [`Texture.GetNativeTexturePtr()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture.GetNativeTexturePtr.html) to the native C++ side as `IntPtr` then use `glTexSubImage2D` to directly modify it. I noticed that most of your questions is about C++ and OpenGL so this shouldn't be hard for someone like you.

As for supporting different graphics APIs, the first to support is OpenGL because that's supported on all **major** platforms. From the Editor, change the Graphics API to OpenGL then start coding. It should work on Windows, Mac, Linux, Android and iOS. If you want to support Direct3D, Metal and Vulkan then go for them too. You just don't have to. **OpenGL is enough for this.**

**2**. Use Shaders

You can combine Unity Shaders and Compute Shaders and still get more performance than `glTexSubImage2D` because this will be happening on the GPU instead of CPU. I personally find shaders complicated so **#1** should be your priority.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `glTexSubImage2D` can be used to update a smaller rectangular portion of a larger texture.

Comment: I know that. What I want to know is is changing pixel in Texture and then Texture.apply() is similar to glTexSubImage2D

Comment: @PankajBansal: well, a Unity texture object surely has some internal state that goes beyond what OpenGL does. So there's that, which may be changed. But as far as OpenGL concerned it really boils down to `glTexSubImage…`; there is simply no other way to modify texture data other than through that, or by performing shader image writes (which would be a helluva awkward way to update texture data from the host program).